# How do I limit webform submissions based on the email address?

Tags: webforms

Is there a way to limit the submissions based on the email address when using the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module in Drupal? Right now, there is a setting to limit using the ip address & cookies but I only want to limit using the email address. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: This question should be migrated to Drupal Answers

Answer (score 3):

Edit the email field in the webform and check both the "mandatory" and "unique" options. That way, it will not except more than 1 submission with the same email address.